# shared/sockets permissions for Thin and Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I deployed Rails application to VDS with Nginx and Thin. I had to add `shared_children.push "tmp/sockets"` to `deploy.rb` cause `cap deploy:setup` doesn't create `tmp/sockets` by default which prevents Thin from starting.

This `shared_children.push "tmp/sockets"` creates `sockets` in `deploy_to/shared` directory.

Nginx worker processes run on behalf of **nginx** user, while `shared/sockets` has **770** permissions and **app1.deployers** owners. That is why nginx cannot read/write sockets files despite socket files theirselves have **777** permissions.

**1. What is better**, to change permissions of shared/sockets to 777 or to add nginx user to deployers group, or to deploy and to run Thin on behalf of nginx user?

I'd like to run each application on behalf of not nginx user but separate user for each app. **2. Does that make sence** practically?

ps

Also I didn't find any mention someone gets permission denied errors in /var/log/nginx/errors.log due to incorrect permissions of shared/sockets. I think I miss something very simple and basic.

Maybe people deploy and on behalf of nginx or www-data users regardless how many applications are deployed to the same server?